# Pyomo in between constraints logical

Tags: pyomo, job-scheduling, mixed-integer-programming

I have a pyomo model where the main decision variable in a job scheduling model is a binary variable y[m,p,t] where y indicates whether job p is allocated to machine m at time slot t where t is just a a time based ordering on each machine.

From this I am able to derive another variable cum_time[m,t] which gives the total cumulative running time on each machine up until time slot t in hours.

Now I want to create another decision variable hourly[m,h] which aggregates the number of jobs starting (or ending) at hour h for every machine. Note that whereas t simply refers to the ordering of the time slot, h should refer to the actual starting hour of each job. So h represents a discretization of the entire time horizon. Ultimately, I want to institute hour-by-hour resource constraints that are not possible with the current formulation.

I tried to derive hourly[m,h] from cum[m,t] but wasn't able to get all the logical constraints working properly.

Is there an obvious trick that I am missing? Obviously, one solution is to rewrite the entire model based on time discretization (h) as opposed to time slot positional ordering (t) but I wanted to ask if there is a smarter way to add these hourly constraints to the current model.

Your help is most greatly appreciated.

John

Edit: In plain python, this is what I am trying to accomplish to assuming that cum_x, hour_x are pyomo Var.

-In plain python

```
import numpy as np

# Random processing times for 50 jobs across 10 machines and 5 job slots

x_rand = np.random.rand(10,5)

# Calculate cumulative running times across each of the 10 machines

cum_x = np.cumsum(x_rand, axis=1)

# Find maximum number of hours needed to run all jobs

max_time = int(np.max(cum_x)) + 1

# Calculate hourly totals. For each discrete hourly time window count how many jobs end at that hourly time window. 

hour_x = np.zeros(shape=(10, max_time))

for m in range(10):
    for t in range(5):
        for h in range(max_time): 
            if cum_x[m,t] >= h and cum_x[m,t] < h+1:
                hour_x[m,h] = hour_x[m,h] + 1

np.sum(hour_x) == 50
```

Comment: For example, I should be able to do something like this: loop through each of cum[m,t] and if cum[m,t] > h and cum[m,t] < h+1 then hour[m,h] = hour[m,h] + 1

Comment: It isn't real clear what the exact relationship is between `t` and `h`.  Are your timeslots (t) hourly?  daily?  Or something different?  If `t` is just an indexed count of hours, then you can just convert `t`-->`h` after the model is run.  It might help if you edit your post and give an example of this relationship and maybe a toy example of what you want from `hourly[m, h]`.  Posting some code is always encouraged and will get you better answers

Comment: Thank you. t is simply the position order on a given machine. So t=0 will be the first job scheduled on a given machine and t=1 will represent the second job scheduled on a given machine and so on. So there is no direct relationship between t and h.

Comment: Okay.....  Your problem description is a bit confusing then.  You said `t` was a *time* slot.....  it is actually a "job slot" or "job sequence number" with no relationship to time.  Now it is unclear how you are handling the flow of time in your model.  You probably need to post some code/example to explain that.  It isn't clear how you would sequence jobs between machines and know when they were available, for example

Comment: In standard  python:

Comment: So each job only needs to be worked on by 1 machine by your example, so you don't need to handle time in your base model, just sequence.  Got it.  If you anticipate "hourly constraints" in the future, this will be very difficult to work with because you will have to implement a bunch of indicator constraints by hour, etc.  I would either switch to hourly time slots if it is important to handle things on an hourly basis.  If your job times are small (relative to hours), you may want to handle time also with a continuous variable.

Comment: If it makes sense with the sequencing you are doing now, you could calculate how many things are done in an hour by multiplying the earlier sequence numbers x job duration.  Would that help?